# selector method never called in NSNotificationCenter

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I am trying to utilize the NSNotificationCenter and for some reason the selector method is never called.

```
- (NewsItem *) loadNewsItemDetail:(NewsItem *)currentNewsItem
{
    self.newsItem = currentNewsItem;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(DownloadNewsItem) name:@"connectionDidFinishLoadingComplete" object:nil];

    return self.newsItem;
}

- (void) DownloadNewsItem:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSString *urlString = [Configuration newsStreamAPIURL:plNewsAPIKey];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{       
    ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connectionDidFinishLoadingComplete" object:nil];

}
```

Any reason why my DownloadNewsItem would never be called based on what I have provided?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a colon in your selector method, because it takes a parameter (an `NSNotification` in this case).

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(DownloadNewsItem:) name:@"connectionDidFinishLoadingComplete" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten `:` symbol after `DownloadNewsItem`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(DownloadNewsItem:)
                                             name:@"connectionDidFinishLoadingComplete"
                                           object:nil];
```